# using javascript to get selected text from an iframe pointing to a different domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

I have an iframe set up that allows the user to browse to a different website with a simple form set up next to it so the user is able to enter information into the form.

This is set up in order to allow the user to quickly refer to the iframe and enter information into the form without having to open the site in a separate window and having to resize the two windows in order to view both at the same time (this was a specific user request).

Now the user has requested that this process of entering information from the form is streamlined a bit more by eliminating the need to 'highlight text > ctrl+c > select correct field in form (eg phone no.) > ctrl + v', so I am looking into seeing if it is possible to just highlight the text to be copied and then automatically update a field in the form using a button or a simple key down event.

I have tried using :

window.frames["myframe"].getSelection().toString();

but this results in an error telling me I don't have permission to access the "getSelection" property, which I believe is because I am trying to access the information of a page on a different domain to mine.

Is there any other way of capturing just the selected text to paste into my form element or will the user have to just deal with the constant copy and pasting manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't perform any JS action** on any `iframe` that has another origin. That's a basic security policy of any web browser. It would be an enormous security flaw.

Comment: thanks, was just checking if there was any other way to do this akin to manually copy and pasting but if there's not then not to worry.